# Try/Catch: Object Exception is not a value

Tags: scala

I am trying to catch different types of exceptions but I am stuck on an error. I imported `scala.util.control.Exception._`

```
try {
        isAuthenticatedJson(f)
    }catch {
      //object RuntimeException is not a value
      case RuntimeException => {}
      //object Exception is not a value
      case Exception => {}
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this (note the underscore):

```
try {
    isAuthenticatedJson(f)
} catch {
  case _: RuntimeException => {}
  case _: Exception => {}
}
```

This is a "typed pattern". See http://www.scala-lang.org/node/120.